# Sort Dataset by Row index after GroupBy

Tags: dataset, sorting

I would like to sort my `Dataset` by its row index. Unlike an ordinary column, this index does not have a name.

```
myDataSet=Dataset[{Association["c1"->"b","c2"->1],Association["c1"->"a","c2"->2],Association["c1"->"a","c2"->3],Association["c1"->"c","c2"->5],Association["c1"->"c","c2"->7],Association["c1"->"b","c2"->4]}]
```

[image]

```
myDataSet[GroupBy["c1"],KeyDrop["c1"]]
```

[image]

The expected order of the `Dataset` is "a", "b", "c".

In the case of multiple row indices, it get's even more complicated.

```
myDataSet2=Dataset[{Association["c0"->"2","c1"->"b","c2"->1],Association["c0"->"2","c1"->"b","c2"->2],Association["c0"->"2","c1"->"a","c2"->3],Association["c0"->"2","c1"->"a","c2"->4],Association["c0"->"1","c1"->"a","c2"->1],Association["c0"->"1","c1"->"a","c2"->2],Association["c0"->"1","c1"->"b","c2"->3],Association["c0"->"1","c1"->"b","c2"->4]}]
```

[image]

```
myDataSet2[GroupBy["c0"],GroupBy["c1"],KeyDrop["c0"],KeyDrop["c1"]]
```

[image]

The expected order is "1", "2", and within each level "a", "b".

**Update**

Following the answer by *kglr*, the `KeySort`method does work for `Dataset`s with a single level index, but does not work directly for multiple indices as it only operates on the first level.

```
myDataSet2[GroupBy["c0"],GroupBy["c1"],KeyDrop["c0"],KeyDrop["c1"]][KeySort]
```

[image]

Comment: `KeySort@myDataSet[GroupBy["c1"],KeyDrop["c1"]]`?

Comment: `myDataSet[GroupBy["c1"],KeyDrop["c1"]][KeySort]` Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
KeySort @ myDataSet[GroupBy["c1"],KeyDrop["c1"]]
```

[image]

Also

```
myDataSet[GroupBy["c1"]/*KeySort,KeyDrop["c1"]]
```

> same picture

**Update:** Multi-level grouping:

```
myDataSetb = Dataset[{Association["c0" -> "1", "c1" -> "b", "c2" -> 1], 
   Association["c0" -> "1", "c1" -> "b", "c2" -> 2], 
   Association["c0" -> "1", "c1" -> "a", "c2" -> 3], 
   Association["c0" -> "1", "c1" -> "a", "c2" -> 4], 
   Association["c0" -> "0", "c1" -> "a", "c2" -> 1], 
   Association["c0" -> "0", "c1" -> "a", "c2" -> 2], 
   Association["c0" -> "0", "c1" -> "b", "c2" -> 3], 
   Association["c0" -> "0", "c1" -> "b", "c2" -> 4]}];

grouped = myDataSetb[GroupBy["c0"], GroupBy["c1"]]

grouped[Sort, ReverseSort]
```

[image]

Comment: +1 for `/*KeySort`. I've never seen `/*`before. The *Help* tells me it's `RightComposition`. That's quite elegant.

Comment: What about multi-level row indices? `myDataSet=Dataset[{Association["c0"->"1","c1"->"b","c2"->1],Association["c0"->"1","c1"->"b","c2"->2],Association["c0"->"1","c1"->"a","c2"->3],Association["c0"->"1","c1"->"a","c2"->4],Association["c0"->"0","c1"->"a","c2"->1],Association["c0"->"0","c1"->"a","c2"->2],Association["c0"->"0","c1"->"b","c2"->3],Association["c0"->"0","c1"->"b","c2"->4]}]` In that case, `KeySort` only sorts the first index.

Comment: @LBogaardt, you mean its grouped version `myDataSet[GroupBy["c0"],GroupBy["c1"],KeyDrop["c1"]]`?

Comment: Yeah, sorry, I should have added this to my Question with more details. Indeed, say I have multiple levels, how can I sort on *all* levels? Preferably, even indicating _Asc_ or _Desc_ per index level. Similar to _SQL_ or _pandas_ etc.

Comment: I updated the original post. I'll keep your answer as 'accepted'.

Comment: @LBogaardt, please see the update.

Comment: Actually, that does not work in general. It worked in this case only because the indices "c0" and "c1" were still included as columns in the dataset. I now used `KeyDrop` to remove them in my OP.